# View Source of draft message in Outlook 2007

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

It is easy to view the HTML source of a received message in Outlook 2007. Just double-click the message to open it in its own window, select the Other Actions button from the Message tab on the ribbon, and select View Source.

How can I view the HTML source for a message draft? There is no Other Actions for a draft.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to click on the Office Orb and select Save-As,(or press alt+f a) save it as html and then open the saved html file with notepad.

Comment: Thanks--too bad I can't use the built-in View Source functionality :(